# Infinitive's Part of Speech in "Scientists have struggled for so many years to find them."

Tags: infinitives, parts-of-speech

Is "to find them" an adverbial of purpose or an adverbial of result?

In other words, which of the following two sentences is closer to the sentence in the subject line:

> 1. Scientists have struggled for so many years and found them.
> 2. In order to find them, scientists have struggled for so many years.

Comment: This question is a better fit for our sister site [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Infinitives are always verbs. They are the main verbs in infinitive clauses. These clauses can be used as nouns, adjectives, or adverbs. Sentence 1 does not contain an infinitive (_found them_ is past tense, not an infinitive). An infinitive clause introduced by _in order_ is an adverbial clause, like Sentence 2, which I would call a purpose infinitive. Actions with purposes sometimes have results; this is not a well-defined distinction. And don't introduce new data in the title; give three examples instead.

Answer (score 1):

I think your question is based on a false premise, that the adverbial phrase *"to find them"* is either always *an adverbial of purpose* or *an adverbial of result.*

In

> it took scientists sixty years to find them,

it's clearly the case that they found them, so that would be in your terminology *an adverbial of result*.

In

> scientists struggled for 25 years to measure the speed of the Earth before Einstein's theory of relativity showed this was impossible,

it's clearly the case that they didn't measure it, so it would be in your terminology *an adverbial of purpose*.

In the original sentence, you can't tell whether they were found or not from the sentence alone.